# Выравнивание блоков

Tags: вёрстка, css

Как без бубна, создания множества дополнительных классов и js сделать так, чтобы блоки не прижимались к левому боку, а выравнивались по центру, независимо от размера экрана?

html

```
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
<div class="class">Текст текст текст текст</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div
{
    background: red;

}

.header
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 1%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 500%;
}
.class{

    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Обернуть все в div
2. Убрать у class float: left;
3. Назначить class margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в .class

justify-content: center;

По идее должно сработать